# How to pass database ID to Rails URL path

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So I have a dropdown menu where it contains all the titles from the database that I created. Whatever title I have selected, I'm trying to pass its numerical value (ID) into URL path parameter from the database.

This is what I have got so far in my index.erb.html file

```
<%= button_to "SHOW", show_articles_link(*Enter ID Parameter*), :method => 'get' %>
```

And in my ArticlesController file, I wrote

```
def show
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

I'm not exactly sure how to pass its ID value into that parameter. I've thought about using JavaScript like

```
var id = document.getElementById('articles').value;
```

But I'm not entirely sure how to pass this variable into the parameter.

Is there another way to do this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a select box listing the Articles, and when a user selects an article from this list, he should be redirected to this article's page?

Answer (score 0):

suppose your showing this `<%= button_to "SHOW", show_articles_link(*Enter ID Parameter*), :method => 'get' %>` button on index page .

so on index page u must have variable like @articles and you are serving it like

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= button_to "SHOW", show_articles_link(article.id), :method => :get
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different ways to solve this problem :

1. **Using a form & submit**

Encapsulate your dropdown menu and your button inside a form.
The form should point to the show action URL, with a GET method.
The dropdown menu should be a select with an element id of "id" (the name of the parameter you want to pass to the show method).
The button should trigger the form's submission.
Assuming your articles are in `@articles`, and that each Article has an `id` and a `title`:

```
<%= form_tag show_articles_link, method: :get do -%>
  <%= select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@articles, "id", "title") %>
  <%= submit_tag "SHOW" %>
<% end -%>
```

2. **Using javascript**

Bind the "change" event of your dropdown menu to a function that updates/rewrites the "href" attribute of your button with the (database) id of the selected article.
Set the button's default href to that of the article selected by default in the dropdown.
Using jQuery to make things easier:

In your view:

```
<%= select_tag :articles, options_from_collection_for_select(@articles, "id", "title") %>
<%= link_to "SHOW", show_articles_link(id: @articles.first.id), id: "myButton", class: "btn" %>
```

In you view (using `<script>` tags) or in a separate javascript asset:

```
$(document).on "change", "#articles", function() {
  $("#myButton").attr("href") = "/article/" + $(this).val();
};
```

Important: you might have to edit the javascript to reflect how your show article route is actually defined. In the javascript code above it's assumed the route is defined as `'/article/:id'`.